# How to include category in the product url in Satchmo?

Tags: python, django, satchmo

I am porting an existing web site to django/satchmo. I want to keep the same url schema than the existing site.

This url schema includes the category of the product. Someting like :

```
/parent-category/category/sub-category/product.html
```

AFAIK, Satchmo doesn't give the possibility to insert the category in the product url.

Is it possible to do this somehow?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible. I finally decided to change the url schemas and to redirect old pages to new ones.